# Sending emails from my users' emails

Tags: email, security, passwords

I know that the title is not a very good one, but bear with me, please. Suppose I want to create a website where people can register and schedule a message and my system will send it at the appropriate time to the person they want (from there email address). I understand that it is not a good idea to ask them for there password and save it in my database. But what else can I do?

Comment: *"But what else can I do"* - It is hard to say because it is not clear what you want to accomplish. Remailers have been around forever, so its not clear why you need a user's credentials. Just pretend the user sent your MTA the email, your email accepted it on good faith it was from the user, and then your MTA delivers it.

Comment: Let's say you want to send me an email two weeks later. I want to make a website where you can just schedule that email and my system will send it to you on the date you chose FROM you email address